# Published aspx.cs file to azure server, But latest code dosent work

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I just published a aspx.cs server code change to my web application from visual studio 2015,with the same azure profile.But the code wont work, it still takes the old code.

When I look at the comparison of aspx.cs files in server and local, it is the same. The new one.

However the changes done to the html part gets reflected, but changes to aspx.cs will not?

Why is it so ? Kindly help

Comment: Restart Application on IIS.

Comment: I did a restart of the web application from the azure portal, but does not work.

Comment: Are you using a Web App project or a Web Site project in VS? See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assume that you are using a Web Site project and your source code is deployed to Azure directly without be compiled. In this situation, the first request to your website could require the site to be compiled, which could result in a delay.

> When I look at the comparison of aspx.cs files in server and local, it is the same. The new one.
>   However the changes done to the html part gets reflected, but changes to aspx.cs will not?

Since you have restarted your web app, please try to precompile your website during publishing as follows:

[image]

Note: Please try to tick the "Precompile during publishing" box, which could leverage all code-behind class files and standalone class files in your project compiled into a single assembly, then put in the web application project's Bin folder. Also, you could check the "Remove additional files at destination" box to empty the website content before publishing your website. For more details, you could follow this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx).